# Is an employer allowed to reserve a position only for a disabled candidate, or to favour a job candidate partly on the basis they are disabled?

Tags: united-kingdom

I'm applying for a job with a disability research team at a local university. All the job description etc appears to be written specifically to be accessible for people who are disabled.

They had an open day for the job. When I went there, they commented that they anticipated that people applying for the job would be disabled (I am not).

I'm going to apply for this job, but I'm curious as to whether they can refuse to give it to me on the grounds that I'm not disabled. Can they?

Edit: I forgot to mention, I am a primary school teacher who has done a lot of work in Special Schools, and with SEN children in mainstream primary schools. So I can plausibly claim to understand the needs of disabled service users, even though I'm not one.

Comment: (IANAL) While they likely can't deny you the job because you aren't disabled, they can most likely favor someone for being disabled because they better understand the needs of the community the job serves.

Comment: Thanks, that prompts me to add something to the question.

Comment: I had a quick read of the Equalities Act. If disabled, you cannot be discriminated against. If able bodied, you cannot be discriminated against on the basis of gender, religion, ethnicity, age, sexuality, etc, but being NOT disabled is not actually protected AFAIK.

Comment: @JohnHC Your comment is the answer IMHO

Comment: @MisterSortOfPositive Foundation of the answer, or a pointer for potential answerers. Law is much more complicated than a quick read of the Equalities Act. Sadly.

Comment: I'd suggest simplifying this to "Is positive discrimination legal in the UK?". That's clearly scoped and is perfectly answerable. The short answer is "No, but positive action is." and an answer can point to .gov sites and legal definitions and answer the general case just fine. But even in its current state **this question is on-topic in my view.**

Comment: The term "positive discrimination" is disputed. If it has legal meaning in UK then so be it, but otherwise using it may be a really bad idea, one that will cause a flame war.  ‘positive measures’ or ‘special measures’ seems to be much safer word choices.

Comment: There are hundreds of companies that hire (Veterans) or are considered starter jobs for (Reformed Criminals) or target giving people a second chances like Goodwill.  My point is you cannot (not pick a candidate) because of they are part of a protected class but you CAN pick them in most cases.  While you can't require a candidate be a reformed criminal, be disabled, or be a veteran, you can as a company have a company vision that hires those classes.

Comment: So are you saying their preference has to be limited to promoting the job to disabled people? They can't refuse to hire non disabled people?

Answer (score 2):

Reading the comments gives mixed messages for this question and it is actually very simple.

No, you cannot be refused a job on the grounds that you are not disabled.

No, they cannot pre-determine that the successful candidate MUST be disabled.

However, if they are looking for a disabled candidate (unofficially) and plenty have applied then as long as they let you interview there is no way you could argue you were rejected based on your lack of disability.

"Positive discrimination" is still considered simply "discrimination" in employment law which means everyone must be given the same opportunity to apply as anyone else.